# What am I doing wrong with this recursive JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here is the entire page:

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/json2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function buildList(point) {
                        if ( !point )
                                return [];
                        children = [];
                        lis = point.children('li');
                        for (index = 0; index < lis.length; index++) {
                                id = $(lis[index]).attr('id');
                                parts = id.split('-');
                                title = $(lis[index]).children('div').text();
                                newObj = {
                                        id: parts[1],
                                        mtype: parts[0],
                                        label: title
                                }
                                ol = $(lis[index]).children('ol');
                               // if (ol.length == 1) {
                               //         newObj['childobjects'] = buildList(ol);
                               // }
                                children.push(jQuery.extend(true, {}, newObj));
                        }
                        return children;
                }
                $(function() {
                        obj = buildList( $('#menu-top') );
                        alert( JSON.stringify(obj) );
                });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<ol id="menu-top" class="sortable ui-sortable">
        <li id="entry-16608">
                <div>Test item 1</div>
                <ol>
                        <li id="entry-16607" ">
                                <div>News, links and random thoughts</div>
                        </li>
                </ol>
        </li>
        <li id="entry-16609">
                <div>How a data retention mandate will likely lead to de facto censorship in the US</div>
        </li>
        <li id="entry-16579">
                <div>Git cheat sheet</div>
        </li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

When I comment out the recursive call, my JSON looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"16608",
      "mtype":"entry",
      "label":"Test item 1"
   },
   {
      "id":"16609",
      "mtype":"entry",
      "label":"How a data retention mandate will likely lead to de facto censorship in the US"
   },
   {
      "id":"16579",
      "mtype":"entry",
      "label":"Git cheat sheet"
   }
]
```

When I uncomment the code, the JSON looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"16607",
      "mtype":"entry",
      "label":"News, links and random thoughts"
   },
   {
      "id":"16607",
      "mtype":"entry",
      "label":"News, links and random thoughts"
   }
]
```

I'm guessing this is the result of ignorance on my part about the finer details of how JavaScript handles scoping and recursion, but I'm at a loss as to what to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a scope problem. You forgot to put `var` in front of **all** variables. This makes the variables global, meaning each function call has access to the same variables (and is overwriting them).

See the fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/uYXYh/

You could further improve the code by making use of more jQuery methods:

```
function buildList(point) {
    if (!point) return [];
    var children = [];
    point.children('li').each(function() {
        var parts = this.id.split('-');
        var newObj = {
            id: parts[1],
            mtype: parts[0],
            label: $(this).children('div').text()
        };
        var $ol = $(this).children('ol');
        if ($ol.length == 1) {
            newObj['childobjects'] = buildList($ol);
        }
        children.push(jQuery.extend(true, {}, newObj)); // not sure why you are
                                                        // doing this instead of
                                                        // children.push(newObj)
    });
    return children;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/uYXYh/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `index` is being declared as a global variable, and is getting mutated on each call to buildList. I think that's your problem (but maybe you're doing that on purpose for something that I'm not seeing). Try changing your for statement to:

```
for(var index=0; index < lis.length; index++){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. That was it. In fact, the mutation issue was pervasive in my code.